# Detecting that a web-worker has been loaded without sending an explicit message

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Is there a way to detect that a web-worker has been loaded. I looked at the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html) but there is only an `error` event. There is no `onload`, `onreade`, `onstatechange` or anything of the sort.

I am looking for an alternative to the [script element onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) event but for web-workers.

I want to do it without the worker explicitly sending a message after load because it is for a library, and I need it to be as general as possible and don't want to impose this restriction on the worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not by design. This [was planned originally](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2008Jul/0110.html), but got taken out later on. I forgot the rationale, but I suspect it is related to certain implementations allowing the allocation of many workers, but only running a couple at the time.

(There are some plans to improve this, in particular if `SharedArrayBuffer` happens, which needs that kind of information, but there's no standard way now.)

A workaround might be to fetch the code in advance and then initiate the worker from a blob URL.